# Understanding the four-dimensional volume form in Action of Lagrangian

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, action, covariance

Into the following part below, I don't understand what is precisely a "`four-dimensional volume form`" implied in the integral below:

For comparison, the Lagrangian defining general relativity is
$$
S=\int d^{4} x \sqrt{-g}\left(\frac{R}{16 \pi G}+\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{M}}\right)
$$
where $g$ is the determinant of the metric, $\sqrt{-g} d^{4}x$ is the four-dimensional volume form, and $\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{M}}$ is the matter term or matter Lagrangian.

I am not an expert in tensor calculus but I have good notions: in Algebra, a form corresponds to the dual of a vector, but here, I have difficulties to pass from classical Lagrangian to Lagrangian density with integral.

Can anyone explain to me the different steps to introduce the `four-dimensional volume form` $\sqrt{-g} d^{4} x$? Any help/issue/track is welcome.

**EDIT 1:** Just a last question, **what is the interest of having 2 system of coordinates** linked bt the relation $c\,dt\,dx\,dy\,dz = \text{det}(J)\,c\,dt\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=\text{det}(J)\,d^4x$ ? **why should we not be dependent of only one metric like in Bianchi identity ?**

**EDIT 2:** A last detail that disturbs me : why write "$\sqrt{-g}$" for the determinant of Jacobian ? I mean why make appear the square root of $-g$ and by the way, what does $g$ represent in this case ? We can't say that $g$ is the negative of squared determinant, can we ?

Any clarification is welcome

Comment: Calculate the 3D version of this for Euclidean space with spherical coordinates and it should become clearer... it’s just $dV=r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$.

Comment: Given a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, what other coordinate-independent volume forms can you construct?

Comment: @G.Smith . Thanks for your answer, I realize that maybe it comes from the using of Jacobian when we have 2 system of coordinates, for example : $\text{d}x\text{d}y=det(J)\,\text{d}\rho\,\text{d}\theta=\rho\text{d}\rho\text{d}\theta$ ?? But in this case, what is the other system of coordinates represented by $\text{d}^{4}x$. Indeed, the first used is $\text{d}ct\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z$ but what about $\text{d}^{4}x$ ?

Comment: $\sqrt{-g}d^nx$ is the volume form because it is invariant under any change of coordinates on a Riemannian manifold. See eq. 2.48 in [Carroll](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll2.html) and the discussion around it. The $\sqrt{-g}$ is the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation.

Comment: @G.Smith Sorry for my lack of culture in G.R but $\text{d}^4x$ is equal to what ? Have we got : $\text{d}ct\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z=\sqrt{-g} d^{4}x$ ? I have  difficulties to represent to myself the quantity $d^{4}x$. Thanks for your patience

Comment: If you are using $ct,x,y,z$ as coordinates then $d^4x=c\,dt\,dx\,dy\,dz$. If you are using $ct,r,\theta,\phi$ then $d^4x=c\,dt\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$. $d^4x$ = $dx^0dx^1dx^2dx^3$ for *any* coordinates. By itself, this isn’t invariant when you *change* coordinates.

Comment: ok, so I may write between the 2 metrics you took ($ct,x,y,z$) and ($ct,r,\theta,\phi$), that $c\,dt\,dx\,dy\,dz = \text{det}(J)\,c\,dt\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=\text{det}(J)\,d^4x$ with $\text{det}(J)= \sqrt{-g}$ the determinant of Jacobian transformation ($ct,x,y,z$) to ($ct,r,\theta,\phi$) ? I know determinant can represent a volume even a volume of $n$ dimension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115538/discussion-between-youpilat13-and-g-smith).